# NServiceBus Saga/Handler Calling Wcf Service

Tags: wcf, handler, nservicebus, saga

Is anyone able to help me correctly call a Wcf service from within an NServiceBus Saga\Handler?

Presently I am making a synchronous call from within a Handler.

However, IIRC, in a while ago on the NServiceBus documentation pages it recommended using a Saga but provided no further details.

My understanding is that a Saga is preferred as it can be persisted while the Wcf call is being processed and then resumed to receive the response.
(The only other thought is that a Saga is preferred as they are generally longer running than Handlers).

What I need help with is the most appropriate way to resume the Saga instance on the reply from the Wcf service.

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 5):

You actually wouldn't want the saga to call any external resource directly.

Instead, the saga would send a message to a handler and that handler would synchronously call WCF and then send a message back with the response.

If the call to WCF times out, the handler would do its automatic retry logic, or potentially the message might end up in an error queue.

The saga would then be able to deal with the logic of what to do if a response is not received within a certain period of time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is a great help.